# Flutter: How to align height of two adjacent widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

In bigger screens this isn't an issue and height of all widgets are the same but in smaller screens sometimes one of them is bigger than others because widgets extends themselves to contain content.

How can I fix it?

```
return ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: _valueBox(), flex: 3, fit: FlexFit.tight),
        Flexible(child: _dueDateBox(), flex: 3, fit: FlexFit.tight),
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(child: _advancePaymentBox(), flex: 3, fit: FlexFit.tight),
        Flexible(child: _priceBox(), flex: 3, fit: FlexFit.tight),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's because the text is overflowing to a new line. There is a widget called ConstrainedBox if you want to enforce a fixed size. You also might want to look at this package, it can dynamically resize your text to fit. https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text

Comment: @omidh I am sorry that I missed `ConstrainedBox` what you comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about to use `GridView`?
I think it's more easier way.

This is just a sample code. I added 2 line text instead of image.

```
Widget _valueBox(){
  return Container(color: Colors.blue, 
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("title"), Text("TestA", style: TextStyle(fontSize:50.0))]));
}
Widget _dueDateBox(){
  return Container(color: Colors.yellow, 
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("title"), Text("This is long text", style: TextStyle(fontSize:50.0))]));
}
Widget _advancedPaymentBox(){
  return Container(color: Colors.green, 
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("title"), Text("TestA", style: TextStyle(fontSize:50.0))]));
}
Widget _priceBox(){
  return Container(color: Colors.pink, 
    child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("title"), Text("This is long text really", style: TextStyle(fontSize:50.0))]));
}

Widget getList(BuildContext context){
  return GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: <Widget>[
          _valueBox(),
          _dueDateBox(),
          _advancedPaymentBox(),
          _priceBox()
        ],
  );
}
```

And, It is the result.
[image]